# AWS Amplify Domain redirect to another domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-amplify, amazon-route53

I have a domain with the name example.co I want to redirect to another domain example.co.uk
the example.co is hosted with aws amplify. i have added the example.co.uk with route53. also, add an S3 bucket for it. Please guide me on what should I do next.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Got this info from: https://read.acloud.guru/how-to-deploy-a-custom-domain-with-the-amplify-console-a884b6a3c0fc

Steps:

1. You need to add the subdomain on the `Domain management` section of the Amplify Console.
2. Then go to the `Rewrites and redirects` section of the Amplify Console. Just add the redirect 302 and add the source and target. i.e. `example.co` --> `example.co.uk`.
3. This may take time to propagate (although for me it was almost instant).

Comment: Not sure on the downvote, but it is the right answer. For more details: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/redirects.html.

Comment: Working for me as well. The settings are sometimes effective immediately.